# Django Models - SQL Equivalent multiple tables join in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to join 3 or more tables in django (ORM ) and fetch the results?
Have created 3 models:

1.student
2.marks
3.details

```
class Student:    
    s_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)    
    s_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  

class Marks:  
    school_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  
    s_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    score = models.IntegerField()  
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)  

class Details:  
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    emailid = models.EmailField()  
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(Marks,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    accomplishments = models.TextField()
```

I need to join these 3 tables and fetch student name,score,status,address_city,email_id,accomplishments.
In SQL we can write like this:

```
select s_name, score, status, address_city, email_id,
accomplishments from student s inner join marks m on
s.s_id = m.s_id inner join details d on 
d.school_id = m.school_id;
```

Please let me know how to achieve same thing using DJANGO codes.

Comment: Good news - Django deals with all the joins for you. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: With your current setup, you'll get multiple related "detail" for each "mark". Did you really mean that? Also, you shouldn't give the plural name for the models.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `_id` for the foreign key names. Given a Mark, the FK field gives access to the entire Student, not the ID. Django creates an underlying database field suffixed with `_id` anyway.

Comment: Also, your classes should probably inherit from `models.Model` to work correctly

Comment: thanks for naming convention related suggestions..@Ralf yes I know that we have to inherit from models.Model..I was looking for the functionality wise result..Whatever names provided in the above classes are just an examples

Answer (score 0):

Some Suggestions for given models:

models.py:

```
class Student:    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  

class Marks:  
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    score = models.IntegerField()  
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)  

class Details:  
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    emailid = models.EmailField()  
    school = models.ForeignKey(Marks,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    accomplishments = models.TextField()
```

Now, Create your mapping model as we create mapping table in sql:

```
class StundetMarksDetailsMap:
  student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  marks = models.ForeignKey(Marks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  details =  models.ForeignKey(Details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

Now you can create your own `queryset` as you want in views.py or where you want:

```
class StudentView(generic.DetailsView):
  model = Student
  template = student_details.html

  //this will return all values related student
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StundetMarksDetailsMap.objects.filter(student=Student)
```

Basically this `get_queryset` returns objects of models which are related to stundet which was picked, use returned objects of Details and Marks to call their corresponding fields in your template. Also use only those fields which you want to display.

Hope this works for you too. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep it simple rather than complicating models which won't be great when you have a lot of data. Keep the student model as the main Class. And store all other info in other tables.

```
class Student:    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    marks = models.ForeignKey(Marks,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Marks:    
    score = models.IntegerField()  
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)  

class Details:  
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=30)  
    emailid = models.EmailField()  
    accomplishments = models.TextField() 

class School:
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     details = models.ForeignKey(Details)
```

Now do the below query

```
student = Student.objects.filter(pk=student_id).filter(school_pk=school_id)

print student.name
print student.marks.score
print student.marks.status
print student.details.address_city
```

For your current models, it's difficult to query. But you can try writing SQL queries itself. Something like this

```
Blog.objects.extra(
    select={
        'entry_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_entry WHERE blog_entry.blog_id = blog_blog.id'
    },
)
```

Follow this 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra